# Solutions for inverses

Tags: linear-algebra

> If A is taller than it is wide, then it is possible for this equation to have no solution. If A is wider than it is tall, then there could be multiple possible solutions.

- (Referring to the possible solutions of inverse of A).

$A \in R^{m \times n}$, if $m>n$, then we can intuitively deduce that this transformation's range, can entirely be described by the basis of the column vectors of $A$. Consequently, the range is $n$-dimensional and hence every point in the range should have an identifying vector in the corange of $A$; hence $A$ should have an inverse.

Let $n>m$, this vector should not have an inverse, say we have a transformation, for example, that projects a $3d$ vector into the $2d$ plane, then the inverse of each point on that plane has an infinite number of values (going up the $z$-axis), hence, no inverse?

In case the question is not clear enough, I read the quoted paragraph and cannot come to terms with how it is true, and I explained why I couldn't. Can someone debate my logic?

Comment: "Consequently, the range is $n$-dimensional..." - not unless the columns are linearly independent. In general all you can say is that the range is at most $n$-dimensional. In any case, if $m > n$ then $A$ cannot be surjective, although it may be injective. Thus it may have a left inverse but it cannot have a right inverse. Similarly, if $m < n$, then $A$ can be surjective but it cannot be injective. Thus it may have a right inverse but it cannot have a left inverse. So, $A$ cannot have an inverse (which by definition is both a left and right inverse) unless $m=n$.

Comment: It's possible, for example if $A$ is a zero matrix with $m> n$, then there is no solution where $A\mathbf v$ is a non-zero vector. And it's possible, for example if $A$ is a zero matrix with $m < n$, then there could be multiple possible solutions where $A\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$.

Comment: @Bungo Oh yeah, that makes sense, stupid question. You should've typed that as an answer though, if you do so, I'll be sure to tick it.

Comment: @Sdavid552 Sure, I'll go ahead and upgrade my comment to an answer now that I know it successfully addresses your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first paragraph, you say: "Consequently, the range is -dimensional..."

This is not true unless the columns are linearly independent. In general, the range of $A$ is equal to the maximum number of linearly independent columns (i.e., the column rank). So, the range is always $\leq n$, and it equals $n$ if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

To address your remarks about inverses:

A linear map (or any function) has a *left* inverse if and only if it is injective (one-to-one), and it has a *right* inverse if and only if it is surjective (onto). And it has an inverse (which by definition is both a left inverse and a right inverse) if and only if it is bijective (both injective and surjective).

If $m > n$, then:

- $A$ cannot be surjective, because the codomain is $\mathbb R^m$ and the $n$ columns cannot span a space of higher dimension than $n$. Therefore $A$ cannot have a right inverse.
- $A$ will be injective, and therefore will have a left inverse, if and only if its columns are linearly independent.

If $m < n$, then:

- $A$ cannot be injective because the number of columns is greater than the dimension of the codomain $\mathbb R^m$, so the columns cannot be linearly independent. Therefore, $A$ cannot have a left inverse.
- $A$ will be surjective, and therefore will have a right inverse, if and only if its columns span $\mathbb R^m$, if and only if there are $m$ linearly independent columns, if and only if there are $m$ independent rows.

In either of the above cases ($m > n$ or $m < n$), $A$ cannot have an inverse: in the first case it cannot have a right inverse and in the second case it cannot have a left inverse.

So, $A$ cannot have an inverse unless $m=n$, and in that case it will have an inverse if and only if it has a left inverse and a right inverse, if and only if it is both injective and surjective, if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent columns (and therefore $n$ linearly independent rows).